# When to use transients, when not to?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, transient

I'm using Wordpress and developed some site-specific plugins for it, additionally my theme is customized to fit the requirements of the plugins in the backend.

The last days I fiddled with transients in Wordpress. In some tutorials they're saying "*If your're using custom queries and their results are cachable: Use a transient*". Sounds good but I'm wondering when to use transients to get a real advantage.
I mean, even when using transients there have to be at least two queries in the background, haven't it? The first one for checking the validity, second one for the transient itself.

So is it really useful to use a transient i.e. for a custom WP_Query?
Thanks a lot for your help and thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fairly straightforward. It's a literal class helper that allows you to store objects in a 'memcache' type fashion. You first set the transient

```
function do_something_here($callback_param = 'value'){
  $key = 'do_something_' . $callback_param;//set the name of our transient equal to the value of the callback param being passed in the function.
  $my_query = get_transient($myKey);  //if we've stored this request before, then use it.
  if($my_query !=== false){
    //we found a previous existing version of this query. let's use it.
    return $my_query;
  }else{
    //it doesn't exist, we need to build the transient.
    //do our database querying here, global $wpdb; etc
    //We are going to pretend our returned variable is 'george'
    $value = george;
    $length = 60*60*24; //how long do we want the transient to exist? 1 day here.
    set_transient($key, $value, $length);
    return $value;
  }
}
```

Now that we have created our trigger and bound it to the name of '$key', we can access it anytime by using the exact value that key implies (which we declared earlier).

```
echo 'I wanted to do something, so : ' . do_something('value') . ' is what i did! ';
```

By utilizing this format you can hold queries in a 'cache' like world and use them to generate your responses. This is similar in a way to using 'trigger' events in MySql. Infact, this is a PORTION of a TECHNIQUE commonly referred to as long polling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the question was another one, sorry for misleading you: Is using a transient more efficient than a simple WP_Query()? In my imagination, the usage of a transient needs more ressources and queries than selecting posts via WP_Query('cat=32');

Comment: That depends on the method and data. If you have a query that's huge, and time consuming, we can store it as a transient. Then that value will always be available by using our transient call, which doesn't require querying the database, it simply monitors it for a change in values. It works a bit like memcache as I mentioned. Therein, transients are a more effective way to use it on sites that have lots of query's going on and several pieces of data. Or, for sites that require things like Push Technology(Long Polling, Comet, etc) ->  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: But when is a query "huge" and when is the usage of transient "huge" in comparison to the query itself? When i.e. selecting five posts from just one table, without joins or subqueries: Isn't the plain query faster and more efficient than caching the result in a transient and requesting the transient, even if the five selected posts stay the same?

Comment: Based on your example, yes, a straight query is best. I doubt it would beat a transient by many miliseconds, but alas, it would. When we say huge I mean 17 joins/unions, 33 cross-table queries, push technology, ajax for updating/deleting/inserting. When you have 1000+ users performing all these actions simultaneously you'll see a huge increase in performance when using 'transient' for them. Although, I would imagine at this stage memcache would be faster. In any event, transients are for things like storing values and making comparisons to make things quicker. Do not use them for page loading.